# Select If....Statement is true.s

Tags: sql-server

[image: Dataset]

I have data with columns EventID, EventDate, W1, W2, W3, W4, W5, WTot, M1, M2, M3, M4, M5, MTot. Wn and Mn are numeric datatype (integers).

I am interested in a select query that will select a next or previous row when the value in say Event1 W1 is selected.

For instance, Select next Events when W1=74 and W4=10?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at LEAD and LAG.

LEAD will look ahead to the next row.  When there are no more rows left, it'll return NULL

```
SELECT W1,   
    LEAD(W1) OVER (ORDER BY EventID) AS NextW1  
FROM Events
```

LAG will look behind for the last row.  On the first row, it'll return null.

```
SELECT W1,   
    LAG(W1) OVER (ORDER BY EventID) AS LastW1  
FROM Events
```